# Entity Framework 6 giving rollback when 2 screen updating same table for different records at same time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, entity-framework-6

I have an web application which is updating a status table from different screen using a stored proecdure .

Each screen calls below code in data layer for updating the status  using stored procedure 
using (var dbContext = new Entities())
            {

```
            using (var dbContextTransaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {

                        dbContext.UpdateStatus( some parameter);
```

Update some more table and sp using same dbContext.

```
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
                    dbContextTransaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
```

---------------                        Log exception in database ---------------

```
                    dbContextTransaction.Rollback();  // Rollback Transaction
                    throw throwNewException;
                }
            }
        }
```

Please help . 
If 2 different logged in user call this method from 2 different screens it give rollback error for one of them. 
Error :Message : Uncommittable transaction is detected at the end of the batch. The transaction is rolled back.

This stored procedure updates old status record for that application and insert a new record with new status .

I am stuck with this issue . Please help

Comment: Have a look at sp_getapplock, it works like a mutex in a stored procedure.

Comment: But I don't want to update the stored procedure . Shouldn't Entity Framework handle the wait during inserts on same table till another transaction is completed . This similar scenarios is on multiple screen with different stored procedures and tables .

Comment: Does the stored procedure start and commit a transaction?

Comment: No I haven't used a transaction in stored procedure . Only on dal layer that too because I am using both stored procedure and linq to update multiple tables in one action.